# NCurses: how to find out whether ABI 6 is supported?

Tags: version, ncurses

Is there a way to find out whether ncurses supports ABI 6?

```
if ( ABI 6 is supported ) {
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see this by comparing the header files.  There are two features which can be checked at compile time:

- the mouse version differs in the header files:

```
     /*                                                                             
      * Identify the mouse encoding version.                                        
      */                                                                            
    -#define NCURSES_MOUSE_VERSION 1                                                
    +#define NCURSES_MOUSE_VERSION 2
```

- the extended-colors symbol is defined:

```
    @@ -374,9 +419,9 @@                                                             
     {                                                                              
         attr_t     attr;                                                           
         wchar_t    chars[CCHARW_MAX];                                              
    -#if 0                                                                          
    +#if 1                                                                          
     #undef NCURSES_EXT_COLORS                                                      
    -#define NCURSES_EXT_COLORS 20110404                                            
    +#define NCURSES_EXT_COLORS 20170729                                            
         int                ext_color;      /* color pair, must be more than 16-bits */
     #endif                                                                         
     }
```

That is, the latter is (in ABI 5) within an ifdef which prevents the `NCURSES_EXT_COLORS` symbol from being defined.  The `NCURSES_MOUSE_VERSION` symbol is always defined, but its value changed.

Comment: Can you give me some suggestions how I could find the right header file within `perl6` code?

Comment: If you're talking about [this](https://github.com/azawawi/perl6-ncurses), it doesn't expose the extended mouse feature.  For extended colors (256 versus 16), if the binding passes back errors, the ABI 5 should return an error if you asked for a color pair value past 255 in `init_pair`, or a color value past 15.

Comment: Is it safe to use the return value of `mousemask` - it returns different numbers with the same mask when using the different ABI versions? `init_pair` return always an error when I use numbers higher than `init_pair(80,7,7)` independently from the ABI version.

Comment: `init_pair` uses the terminal description; if that's `xterm-256color` then ABI 6 would allow larger pair- and color-values.  If that's an 8-color description (use `infocmp` to see), you'd get errors in any case with ABI 5 or 6.  The mouse interface in that code lacks the definitions for button 5 (doesn't support ABI 6).

Comment: There is a `colors#8` in the output of `infocmp`. I added the required lacking definitions in my code.